# In subfigure, the figures come with alphabet in Russian. I want it in English!

Tags: babel

I am using package:

```
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
```

Now, when I use Figures and subfigures, I have alphabet in Russian, I want it to be in English. Note that I use Russian style of thesis. If I remove russian from mode above,  some russian words would be not recognized. So what should I do in this case? I don't know if there is a similar question, if so, then put a comment here and I will remove the question.

For example, if I have two figurs, then it comes as: (а) and (б) instead of (a) and (b)

---

Update: I add some pictures

[image: The code]
[image: The result of this code]

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a small, compilable example that generates the issue you are looking to correct. There are actually several ways to create subfigures; in order to be able to come with a fix, it's crucial to have information on what's going on.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to a single figure and put that into a minimal document that shows what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry but that's not what we're asking for. Don't post code fragments. Put the code into a compilable document and post that as code, not an image from your editor.

Comment: Possibly pass language options to class rather than direct to `babel`. But that's just a guess, since it is impossible to tell.